# Setting editor and publisher to none and redeclare these fields as undefined

Tags: biblatex

I asked for checking large bibliographies for series and number and got this question answered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/582962/18561. I wanted to extend this to publisher and editor fields but they have a different type and I did not manage to set things up according to the hint in the comments. Name fields and list fields seem to be different. So: how can this be done?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{seriescheck.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal, skipout]{optseries}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[
  book,mvbook,inbook,
  collection,mvcollection,incollection
]{optseries}
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[
  book,mvbook,inbook,
  collection,mvcollection,incollection]
{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{series}
  }
  \constraint[type=conditional]{
    \antecedent[quantifier=all]{
      \constraintfield{series}
    }
    \consequent[quantifier=all]{
      \constraintfield{number}
    }
  }
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  datamodel=seriescheck,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource=series, match=\regexp{\Anone\Z}, final]
       \step[fieldset=number, fieldvalue=none]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{series}{%
  \ifdefstring{\NewValue}{none}
    {\def\NewValue{}}
    {}}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{number}{%
  \ifdefstring{\NewValue}{none}
    {\def\NewValue{}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  series       = {none},
}
@book{worman,
  author       = {Worman, Nancy},
  title        = {The Cast of Character},
  date         = 2002,
  publisher    = {University of Texas Press},
  location     = {Austin},
}
@collection{omeara,
  editor       = {O'Meara, Dominic J.},
  title        = {Studies in {Aristotle}},
  date         = 1981,
  series       = {Studies in Philosophy and the History of Philosophy},
  number       = 9,
  publisher    = {The Catholic University of America Press},
  location     = {Washington, D.C.},
  pages        = {161-191},
}
@book{aristotle:poetics,
  author       = {Aristotle},
  title        = {Poetics},
  date         = 1968,
  editor       = {none},
  series       = {Clarendon {Aristotle}},
  publisher    = {none},
  location     = {Oxford},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List and name fields are quite a bit more complicated implementation-wise.

Often you don't get to see that and the only thing you have to worry about is using the appropriate commands for lists and name fields instead of fields. Here you will need `\DeclareListInputHandler` and `\DeclareNameInputHandler` instead of `\DeclareFieldInputHandler`.

That is, however, not enough, because the internal structure of lists and name fields is more complex than that of a field. For a field its contents are saved directly in a macro, but lists and name fields have a more complex structure. So while `none` in the input comes out as `none` for a field, the internal representation of `none` for a list is `{none}` and for a name it is `{{hash=334c4a4c42fdb79d7ebc3e73b517e6f8}{family={none}, familyi={n\bibinitperiod}}}` (the hash in particular is subject to change if the Unicode algorithms are updated, you can grab the correct has from the `.bbl` file). So you need to test against slightly different values for `\NewValue`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{seriescheck.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal, skipout]{optseries}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[
  book,mvbook,inbook,
  collection,mvcollection,incollection
]{optseries}
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[
  book,mvbook,inbook,
  collection,mvcollection,incollection]
{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{series}
    \constraintfield{publisher}
    \constraintfield{editor}
  }
  \constraint[type=conditional]{
    \antecedent[quantifier=all]{
      \constraintfield{series}
    }
    \consequent[quantifier=all]{
      \constraintfield{number}
    }
  }
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  datamodel=seriescheck,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource=series, match=\regexp{\Anone\Z}, final]
       \step[fieldset=number, fieldvalue=none]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{series}{%
  \ifdefstring{\NewValue}{none}
    {\def\NewValue{}}
    {}}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{number}{%
  \ifdefstring{\NewValue}{none}
    {\def\NewValue{}}
    {}}

\DeclareNameInputHandler{editor}{%
  \ifdefstring
    {\NewValue}
    {{{hash=334c4a4c42fdb79d7ebc3e73b517e6f8}{family={none}, familyi={n\bibinitperiod}}}}
    {\def\NewValue{}}
    {}}

\DeclareListInputHandler{publisher}{%
  \ifdefstring{\NewValue}{{none}}
    {\def\NewValue{}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  series       = {none},
}
@book{worman,
  author       = {Worman, Nancy},
  title        = {The Cast of Character},
  date         = 2002,
  publisher    = {University of Texas Press},
  location     = {Austin},
}
@collection{omeara,
  editor       = {O'Meara, Dominic J.},
  title        = {Studies in {Aristotle}},
  date         = 1981,
  series       = {Studies in Philosophy and the History of Philosophy},
  number       = 9,
  publisher    = {The Catholic University of America Press},
  location     = {Washington, D.C.},
  pages        = {161-191},
}
@book{aristotle:poetics,
  author       = {Aristotle},
  title        = {Poetics},
  date         = 1968,
  editor       = {none},
  series       = {Clarendon {Aristotle}},
  publisher    = {none},
  location     = {Oxford},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography without "none" values in the output.]